# Toslink to Coax not working as supposed to

Tags: audio, coaxial

So i've recently bought a home cinema audio set to hook up to my pc. The connection on my Sound card was a toslink and the connector on the set (which is where the amplifier is integrated into the subwoofer) is a coaxial connection. I googled a bit and i found no sound difference between the two so i bought a toslink to coaxial converter and hooked everything up. The issue i'm having is that i cant seem to get it to work. When i boot up my system the sub makes a pop to indicate its getting signal (its always powered on) but after that i cant see it anywhere in my settings.

(Relevant) Hardware

- Sound card : Asus Xonar DGX
- Regular toslink cable
- Konig audio converter (KNACO2501)
- Regular coax cable
- JBL 146-230 Home cinema set

Any help and/or advice is greatly appreciated

[image: Screenshot]

Note: When i connect my headset to the sound card it works fine so its not my sound card acting up.

Answer (score 0):

Does the input panel on your JBL sound system look like this? [image: JBL Audio System]

The problem with this is it does not have a SPDIF coaxial input on it, only left and right analog RCA inputs and an analog LFE (low frequency effects) input.  Frankly, I don't see any indicator that this JBL sound system supports digital audio.(Toslink is optical digital connection, while there are coaxial digital RCA connections, this JBL system does not appear to have one).

An alternative way you could connect your sound card to the JBL system is use a 1/8" (3.5mm) to 2 RCA adapter like this:
[image: 3.5mm to 2 RCA Adapter]
plug it into the green "Front" jack on your sound card and plug the RCAs into the line in jacks on the JBL sound system.

Lastly, on the sound Playback settings on your PC, ensure the output device (the middle one in your pic) is configured for "stereo" so it won't split the sound output between the other jacks on your sound card (black and orange).  The connection will be analog stereo (not digital surround, not sure how the JBL sound system will distribute the stereo signal over its' speakers). I realize this is not exactly what you're looking for, but it would work until you find a better solution.